# Overloading static properties with PHP

Tags: php, overloading, static-libraries

I'm trying to automate the process of accessing libraries in the framework I use (CodeIgniter) but am running in to some issues.

Codeigniter currently loads libraries like this:

```
$this->CI->load->library('name');
$this->CI->name->method();
```

Needless to say that this is a whole bunch of code for something that could be achieved with far less.

I would like to access my lib like this:

```
_Lib::name->method();
```

The _Lib class will then take care of loading the right lib (or directing the loading of that lib to the loader class in this case).

However, above code results in error "unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR".

My end goal is to be able to talk to libraries and have them load on-demand with as little code as possible, and without initializing a global variable.

Any ideas? Keeping in mind that it needs to look as usable and self-explanatory as possible.

I'd like to avoid using something like _Lib('name')->method() as it's quite tedious to write that every time.

**Edit:**

I ended up creating a default Library which I extend my Libraries from, the default Library has properties which direct the loading of other libraries (or models, or helpers, or .. etc) to the appropreate loader, so I can do

```
$this->lib->name->method();
```

Thanks everyone for your answers

Comment: Im sorry, but what is the real diff between _Lib::name->method();
 and _Lib('name')->method() ? two characters?. That's not really a lot, is it? Hardly "tedious". If it is, may i suggest an editor that'll help you with things?

Comment: It's just a personal preference, I don't like working with quoted strings where it's not absolutely needed. I actually use Komodo with tab completion so you're right, it's not that tedious. I just said tedious for lack of a better word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written it, _Lib::name is a class constant. Did you mean `_Lib::$name->method();` ?

Comment: You're right, that was my error. I've been working with CodeIgniter too long, I've forgotten how to use static classes :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The "unexpected `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`" error means that your call to `_Lib::name` did not return an object from which to chain off the method call. Technically, `_Lib::name` returns the value of the class constant `name` in `_Lib`. You are trying to do

```
class _Lib
{
    const name;
}
_Lib::name->method();
```

but a constant cannot hold an object, so no `->`.

You do not want to convert your library to static calls, [because anything static couples to the global scope and is much harder to test](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html). Just keep using what CI offers out of the box.

If you want to have one class to globally manage your other classes, consider using a [Dependency Injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) [Container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), like the one offered in [Symfony Components](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon but it's the syntax check that gives me that error, it has nothing to do with with the property being available. Also I am only providing a shortcut (or trying to) to the CI->load->library() function, I am not overwriting it.

Comment: @Nathan sorry, my bad. It's not refering to the class property, but a constant. same effect though. The reason you get the error already when PHP parses the code is because constants cannot be objects and thus you cannot use `->` (`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`) after fetching the value of one.